# Is it possible to specify a sequence of PreLaunch tasks and a tear down sequence for when a task completes?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

Is it possible to specify the following using Visual Studio code tasks :

1. Define sequential prelaunch tasks of `dotnet build` and `docker-compose up --build -d`
2. When the task ends then launch the equivalent of a tear down process:

   a. docker-compose down

Comment: look at **Compound** Tasks

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution with help from github discussions. Posting here also. Used compound tasks to define the workflow as suggested in comment. Used `dependsOn` and `dependsOrder` json keys to specify task sequence.

Included tasks.json below as a full example for anyone else that has a similar question.

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "start docker services",
            "command": "docker-compose up -d",
            "type": "shell",
            "isBackground": true,
            "problemMatcher": [
                {
                    "pattern": [
                        {
                            "regexp": ".",
                            "file": 1,
                            "location": 2,
                            "message": 3,
                        }
                    ],
                    "background": {
                        "activeOnStart": true,
                        "beginsPattern": "^(Creating network)$",
                        "endsPattern": "^(Creating|Recreating|Starting) (kafka|service-minio|mqtt) ... (done)$",
                    }
                },
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Docker"
            },
            "presentation": {
                "focus": true
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "stop docker services",
            "command": "docker-compose down",
            "type": "shell",
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Docker"
            },
            "presentation": {
                "focus": true
            },
        },
        {
            "label": "collect test coverage (release)",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "test",
                "--configuration:Release",
                "--settings:${workspaceFolder}/Tests/coverlet.runsettings",
                "--collect:XPlat Code Coverage",
                "WebApp.sln"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "group": "test"
        },
        {
            "label": "collect test coverage (debug)",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "test",
                "--configuration:Debug",
                "--settings:${workspaceFolder}/Tests/coverlet.runsettings",
                "--collect:XPlat Code Coverage",
                "WebApp.sln"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "group": "test"
        },
        {
            "label": "create coverage report",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "reportgenerator",
                "-reports:${workspaceFolder}/Tests/**/coverage.cobertura.xml",
                "-targetDir:${workspaceFolder}/CoverageReports",
                "-assemblyfilters:-Minio;-WebApp.Testing.Mocks;-xunit.*;-WebApp.Blazor.UnitTests;-WebApp.Testing.Utils;-Bunit.*;-Humanizer",
                "-classfilters:-Cyotek.Collections.Generic.*"
            ],
            "presentation": {
                "focus": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "group": "test",
        },
        {
            "label": "test (debug)",
            "dependsOrder": "sequence",
            "dependsOn": [
                "start docker services",
                "clean-test-results",
                "collect test coverage (debug)",
                "create coverage report",
                "stop docker services"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "presentation": {
                "focus": true
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "test (release)",
            "dependsOrder": "sequence",
            "dependsOn": [
                "start docker services",
                "clean-test-results",
                "collect test coverage (release)",
                "create coverage report",
                "stop docker services"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "presentation": {
                "focus": true
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "test (docker)",
            "command": "docker-compose -f docker-compose-test.yml up --abort-on-container-exit --build --exit-code-from webapp --remove-orphans",
            "type": "shell",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Docker"
            },
            "presentation": {
                "focus": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```